# SQL Server Performance related

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I have a SQL query and two restores of the same database of different dates. One restore is of 7th Nov and another of 10th Dec. The query runs for 5 hours on database restore of 7th Nov and the same query runs in 23-25 seconds in database restore of 10th Dec.

I compared the indexes on both the databases of the tables involved in the query but indexes are similar in both. Then I checked the query execution plan of the same query on both the database restores. Found many differences in both the Execution plans. In the query execution plan of 7th Nov database restore I see many Nested Joins as compared to that in 10th Dec database restore. The place where Nested Join is used by SQL Server in 7th Nov database, at the same place Merge Join is used in 10th Dec database.

Could anyone please help explain why do we have this discrepancy in query execution plan and also whether why exactly the query is running slow in 7th Nov database.

Comment: Out of date statistics?

Comment: Try to rebuild indexes on the tables in both databases

Comment: Impossible without seeing said execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Index fragmentation and REBUILD\REORGANIZE the required indexes and check again Query performance.

Comment: Thanks..will do that and check